# Give a name to a rule in Makefile

Tags: makefile

Simply put I want to give a name to a rule in my Makefile:

```
A.ext : B.ext
    compute A.ext from B.ext
```

so that I get something like this:

```
.PHONY : my_rule
A.ext : my_rule
my_rule : B.ext
    compute A.ext from B.ext
```

But this is not yet equivalent to the first, since `my_rule` is always executed even if B.ext hasn't changed. How can I achieve equivalence?

This is the trimmed output of `make -d`:

```
Considering target file `A.ext'.
  Considering target file `my_rule'.
   File `my_rule' does not exist.
    Considering target file `B.ext'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `B.ext'.
    No need to remake target `B.ext'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `my_rule'.
  Must remake target `my_rule'.
```

(The reason I want this is that I have another rule `C.ext :| my_rule`.)

Comment: You will run into the same 'always runs' problem with that `C.ext` target as you did with the `A.ext` target. Phony targets [should not be](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html#Phony-Targets) the prequisite of real target files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.PHONY : my_rule
my_rule: A.ext
A.ext : B.ext
    compute A.ext from B.ext
```

Or [better](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
.PHONY : my_rule
my_rule: A.ext
A.ext : B.ext
    compute $@ from $<
```